# Cesium - Display video with Transparency on Polygon

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I've used a .webm as a material for a rectangle.  The video plays, but everywhere it should be transparent, there is instead a white background.

Javascript:

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById('video');

var tv = viewer.entities.add({
    rectangle : {
        coordinates : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-80.0, 15.0, -70.0, 25.0),
        height : 50000,
        material : videoElement
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="videos">
    <video id="video" style="display: none;" autoplay="" loop="" crossorigin="" controls = "">
      <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm">
     </video>
  </div>
</body>
```

Editting the `background-color` of the `video` element or the `div` it's contained in doesn't alter the color of the background that replaces the transparency in the video.  I've tried to edit the `translucent` property of the material after creating the entity by calling

`tv.rectangle.material.translucent = true;`

but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  Is there a way to display videos with transparency in Cesium?

Comment: Can you share the video in question?

Comment: @MatthewAmato http://i.imgur.com/q6bBdV1.gif Imgur wouldn't let me upload the .webm, but here's the .gif I converted to .webm.

Comment: This may be related to [issue #3459](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/3459).